# Umlaut encoding: tar on Mac Lion

Tags: mac-osx, unix, tar, encoding

I have a tar archive created on an old Unixware machine using ISO8859-1 encoding. When I try to extract it under Macosx Lion, I experience a bit of weirdness with German umlauts. For instance:

I open a terminal.app window with the encoding set to "ISO8859-1" and set my locale like this:

```
export LANG=de_DE.ISO8859-1
export LC_ALL=de_DE.ISO8859-1
```

then take a peek at the archive:

```
dhcp202:Downloads frank$ tar tvf backup.tar home/frank
x home/frank/
x home/frank/Präferenzen/
```

note that the "ä" is displayed correctly

I then unpack the archive with

tar xvf backup.tar home/frank

the "ä" is also displayed correctly in the output from tar, but when I list the directory contents, I see:

```
dhcp202:Downloads frank$ ls home/frank
Pr%E4ferenzen
```

What's up with that?

Comment: What is the result from `file -I {filename}`?

Comment: application/x-directory; charset=binary

Comment: I tried the same archive, same actions on a Linux box and a Unixware7 box, without any trouble. Seems to only happen on the mac. Maybe HFS+ has a problem with ISO8859?

Answer (score 1):

Filenames on HFS+ are in UTF-8 format, not in any other encoding (well, except MacRoman for old files).  You can see code related to that in the [kernel source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/hfs/hfs-407.30.1/core/); for example, in `getdirentries_callback()` in `hfs_catalog.c`.